# Get name of day from month, year, and day

Tags: language-agnostic, date

Does anyone know a way to convert a month, year, and day into the day's name for any year?  Example:

```
function convert(day, year, month)
...
return "Monday"
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what language?

Comment: I need a formula, not a way to do it in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method:

> This method uses codes for different
>   months and years to speed up the
>   calculation of the day of the week.
>   You might even be able to memorize the
>   codes. We'll use December 16, 2482 as
>   an example.
>
> Take the last 2 digits of the year. In
>   our example, this is 82.
>
> Divide by 4, and drop any remainder.
>   82 / 4 = 20, remainder 2, so we think
>   "20."
>
> Add the day of the month. In our
>   example, 20 + 16 = 36.
>
> Add the month's key value, from the
>   following table.  Jan Feb Mar Apr May
>   June July Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec  1 4 4
>   0 2 5 0 3 6 1 4 6
>
> The month for our example is December,
>   with a key value of 6. 36 + 6 = 42.
>
> If your date is in January or February
>   of a leap year, subtract 1. We're
>   using December, so we don't have to
>   worry about this step.
>
> Add the century code from the
>   following table. (These codes are for
>   the Gregorian calendar. The rule's
>   slightly simpler for Julian dates.) 
>   1700s 1800s 1900s 2000s  4 2 0 6
>
> Our example year is 2482, and the
>   2400s aren't in the table. Luckily,
>   the Gregorian calendar repeats every
>   four hundred years. All we have to do
>   is add or subtract 400 until we have a
>   date that is in the table. 2482 - 400
>   = 2082, so we look at the table for the 2000s, and get the code 6. Now we
>   add this to our running total: 42 + 6
>   = 48.
>
> Add the last two digits of the year.
>   48 + 82 = 130.
>
> Divide by 7 and take the remainder.
>   This time, 1 means Sunday, 2 means
>   Monday, and so on. A remainder of 0
>   means Saturday.

[How to calculate the day of the week](http://mathforum.org/dr/math/faq/faq.calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

A quickl google for "day of week from date algorithm" showed up [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week)

But depending on the dates you need to work with, beware the [strange history of Gregorian calendar adoption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#History)